# Why wasn't Thorin aware about the state of Mirkwood and the Old Forest Road?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

In The Hobbit, in the Queer Lodgings chapter, Beorn explains to the company the dangers that they might face through Mirkwood:

> “But your way through Mirkwood is dark, dangerous and difficult,” he said...

And the dwarves seem like they had no idea about it, or at least they didn't seem to consider crossing Mirkwood that dangerous:

> But their spirits sank at his grave words, and they all felt that the adventure was far more dangerous than they had thought

Wasn't Mirkwood in this dark / dangerous state when the dwarves were still in Erebor and when they fled Erebor, since Sauron was in Dol Guldur during that time? Is the more detailed history of Mirkwood something that Tolkien only considered afterwards (when writing LoTR)? (I guess a possible explanation is that Mirkwood was in a slightly better state when they left Erebor, since Sauron was gradually getting stronger)

Is there any information available regarding how the Dwarves fled south from Erebor and arrived in Dunland? (e.g. if they crossed Mirkwood via the Old Forest Road etc) Because the company's original plan was to cross via the Old Forest Road:

> By his advice they were no longer making for the main forest-road to the south of his land

Was the Old Forest Road known to be "open" when the Dwarves fled Erebor? Wouldn't at least Gandalf, who had visited Mirkwood more recently be aware of the state of the road (and Mirkwood), which according to Beorn:

> Beorn had warned them that that way was now often used by the goblins, while the forest-road itself, he had heard, was overgrown and disused at the eastern end and led to impassable marshes where the paths had long been lost

Comment: I don't think there is an in-universe explanation; it's just that _The Hobbit_ was written before Tolkien thought of any of that other stuff.

Comment: In the first chapter Thorin says they will make their way east to the Long Lake and the "fun" would start then, and Gandalf says a long time before then if he know s anything about the roads east.

Comment: And it is possible that an army sized group of Dwarves did use the Old Forest Road when fleeing  Erebor and didn't have much trouble with being atttacked.  And an actual army or two of Dwarves could have marched to the Dwarf and Orc War from the east along the Old Forest Road, and then back home after the war.  Possibly the road became really dangerous after that (andno army sized groups traveled it that could bet off attackers), became disused, and the eastern end stopped bing maintaned by men east of the forest, turning into bogs.

Comment: Mirkwood is very large, with the northern end being quite far from the southern end where Dol Guldur is. The exact nature of the forest probably changes over time, as Sauron and/or the Nazgul first are here, then flee, then come back, etc. Even as late as 2851, it seems things aren't so bad that Saruman refusing to countenance an attack on Dol Guldur isn't seen as immediately suspicious.

Comment: Out of universe, The Hobbit was not written with the later history established by The Lord of the Rings in mind. When it was written, it sufficed that Mirkwood was not dangerous, now it is. No real background is given for *why* that may be the case. The Necromancer is mainly present as a reason why going south around Mirkwood is not an option, not a real reason why crossing the forest will be dangerous.